# How to output jquery code in InnerHTML function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to output jquery code in innerHTML function, here i provide simple example of problem, if i output var b than it works but a doesnt.

```
<p class="test">a</p>
<script>
document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].innerHTML = myFunc(); 
function myFunc() {
var b = "hey";
var a = $(".test").text("F:\\PROD\\DATA\\Logglistor\\Logglistor " + new Date().getFullYear());
return a;
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: All the javascript links are right , i just didnt add them here!

Comment: Hi @Pikolinos, I don't understand what it is that you want to output. You want: "F:\\PROD\\DATA\\Logglistor\\Logglistor 2018" to be the output?

Comment: That's some very muddled code. For one thing you have syntax errors (*always* check the console.)

Comment: Yes i try to ouput :"F:\\PROD\\DATA\\Logglistor\\Logglistor 2018"

Comment: Then @Mamun answer is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return text from the function and also you have to concatenate (`+`) the year with the other part of the string:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0].innerHTML = myFunc(); 
function myFunc() {
  var b = "hey";
  var a = "F:\\PROD\\DATA\\Logglistor\\Logglistor " + new Date().getFullYear();
  return a;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="test">a</p>
```

Comment: my problem was this line $(".test").text , i added twice to innerHTML and had [Object object] problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You must concat your string in `.text()`

Like that :

```
var a = $(".logglistPath").text("F:\\PROD\\DATA\\Logglistor\\Logglistor " + new Date().getFullYear())
```

Comment: i made mistake writing it here , it doesnt help

Comment: Yes sorry i see it after.
Why did you do $('.logglistPath) ? Because here, you get the element and you set the content. So after a is a jquery object, not a string

Comment: Ahah no probleme ! :)